# Duplicate Checks with Multiple Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing some manual duplicate checks on my database, and have a complicated case.

I need to check for duplicate rows based on a value in Column A, which I have done. However, in this specific case, there might be multiple records that have the same value for Column A but a different value for Column E.

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableA_1 on fID = hID
WHERE dateCreated > '2013-05-08 00:00:00'
GROUP BY ColumnA
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I now need to filter out duplicates for ColumnA where ColumnE is different, or unique. I have added psuedocode to my original query

```
SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableA_1 on fID = hID
WHERE dateCreated > '2013-05-08 00:00:00'
AND ColumnE is not unique
GROUP BY ColumnA
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can't you just group by columnE too?

Comment: The term "different, or unique" is unclear.  Different than what?  Unique in what way?

Comment: Unique as in, ColumnA is another identifier. I am filtering duplicates based on this, so if Row 1:ColumnA = 10, I only want that record to show up if Row n:ColumnA also = 10. However, this would be permissible if Row 1:ColumnA = 10 and Row 1:Column E = Blue, and Row n:ColumnA = 10 and Row n:Column A = Red. Because ColumnA is the same, but Column E is still unique, I want to filter those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY clause on a ColumnA column and HAVING clause on DISTINCT ColumnE

```
SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableA_1 on fID = hID
WHERE dateCreated > '2013-05-08 00:00:00'
GROUP BY ColumnA
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnE) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add **ColumnE** into the grouping, as shown below:

```
    SELECT ColumnA, ColumnE, COUNT(*) TotalCount
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableA_1 on fID = hID
    WHERE dateCreated > '2013-05-08 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnE
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: The only reason this is worrying me is because running this came back with only 5 overall duplicates, in a table of over 500,000 records. Maybe I'm not giving myself enough credit...